# How can I delete a row in a case system in MS Word 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I gave up trying to make MS Word work with LaTeX syntax, so I decided to learn to use its equation system. I'm using MS Word for Mac, 2011. I wanted to insert a case structure. I usually accidentally insert new cases, like this:

[image]

See, the fourth case there was unintentional, and I would like to get rid of it. When I select it (blue highlighted), and press backspace or delete, nothing happens: it just highlights the entire structure:

[image]

And pressing backspace/delete again, it will just delete the entire structure.

How can I delete a row in a case system in MS Word 2011 for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is to click the down arrow at the right of the equation, select "Linear", then delete the necessary parts in the linear version of the equation. Then switch back to "Professional"

Precisely how to delete an element depends on what your equation actually consists of, but in structures laid out as matrices, in the Linear format you will typically see an "&" separating each horizontal element and an "@" separating each vertical element, so deleting the final "@" may be what you need here.

Because of the way Word "builds up" equations, even working with the Linear format can be a bit tricky, but I don't know of another way (except perhaps using code).